# What does a complete complex number in NumPy's mgrid do?

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

I am trying to figure out how NumPy's mgrid function works and I read that the syntax creating a simple array works like this:

Arguments are separated by `:`. First number gives the start, second number the stop.

If you give a real number e.g. `1` as third argument you fix the step-size (stop excluded)

```
np.mgrid[-5:5:1]

[-5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4]
```

If you give an imaginary third argument you give the number of elements as the coefficient. This time stop included. E.g. `5j` gives

```
np.mgrid[-5:5:5j]

[-5.  -2.5  0.   2.5  5. ]
```

Straightforward enough. I come from a mathematics background and got to know complex numbers with a real and an imaginary part.

`z in C --> z = x + iy`

with real valued `x` and `y`. So I wondered what would happen if one used a complex number that has both a real and an imaginary part and I got this result

```
np.mgrid[-5:5:1+5j]

[-5.         -2.56039219 -0.12078439  2.31882342  4.75843122]
```

Can someone explain what just happened internally?

Comment: The code is available for reading.  `mgrid` is an instance of class that has its own `__getitem__` method (indexing).  The interpreter converts '-5:5:1+5j' to a slice object.  `mgrid` examines these slices, and depending on the "step" value either calls `np.arange` or `np.linspace`.   The use of the imaginary value here is just a notational convenience; it's not a real complex number.

Comment: Looking at the code, I don't see `linspace`.  I think it was there before, but now it appears to just use `arange`.  Somehow the step is derived from `np.abs(1+5j)`.  We could work out what's happening, but the use of `1+5j` is not documented and what happens should be seen as a curiosity, not an intentional design feature.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's easy to understand that

```
np.mgrid[-5:5:5j] 
[-5.         -2.56039219 -0.12078439  2.31882342  4.75843122]
```

means that 5 numbers between -5 and 5 with an equivalent step size.

5j can be understood as 0 + 5j. The total numbers between -5 and 5 are determined by the length of the complex number instead of the imaginary part.

In np.mgrid, we can see the internal code that it uses:

```
step= abs(Re+Imj)
length = int(step_size)
if step != 1:
        step = (Interval)/float(step-1)
```

Apparently, the real part of the complex number increases the number and changes the step size.

For example:

```
[-5:5:4+5j]
6 = int(abs(4+5j))

array([-5.        , -3.14921894, -1.29843788,  0.55234318,  2.40312424,
        4.2539053 ])
```

The number would be 6. And we can compute the step_size by

```
step = (key.stop-start)/float(step-1)
```

where key.stop is -5, start equals 5. The final step equals to

```
[in]: 10/(abs(4+5j) -1)
[out]: 1.8507810593582121
```

It also shows that np.mgrid[-5:5:4+5j] equals np.mgrid[-5:5:5+4j]

However, the question is how to use it? I don't know, but I think it should be understood from

```
np.mgrid[Re1+Xj : Re2 +Yj: Re3+ Zj]
```

Answer (score 1):

`mgrid` uses `np.lib.index_tricks.ndgrid` class.  The use of the complex step is complicated.  I remember at one time it use `np.linspace`, taking the integer part of the `5j` as the number of samples.  Now I don't see use of `linspace`.  It's either `arange` or some home-grown equivalent, which is presumably faster when making a multidimensional grid.

But I've been able to replicate the numbers with:

```
In [247]: step = 5j
In [248]: np.mgrid[0:5:5j]
Out[248]: array([0.  , 1.25, 2.5 , 3.75, 5.  ])

In [249]: x = 5/(float(np.abs(step))-1)
In [250]: np.arange(0,5+x,x)
Out[250]: array([0.  , 1.25, 2.5 , 3.75, 5.  ])
```

and for:

```
In [251]: step = 1+5j
In [252]: x = 5/(float(np.abs(step))-1)
In [253]: x
Out[253]: 1.219803902718557
In [254]: np.mgrid[0:5:step]
Out[254]: array([0.        , 1.2198039 , 2.43960781, 3.65941171, 4.87921561])
In [255]: np.arange(0,5+x,x)
Out[255]: 
array([0.        , 1.2198039 , 2.43960781, 3.65941171, 4.87921561,
       6.09901951])
In [256]: np.arange(0,5,x)
Out[256]: array([0.        , 1.2198039 , 2.43960781, 3.65941171, 4.87921561])
```

This isn't an exact duplicate, but the numbers match well enough to identify the step size that it's using.

In any case using a full complex number is not documented.  It works, but the result is not easily understood.